# Open Windows Form only once in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid multiple instances of windows form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp)

I want to show open form only once in an application without creating them as MDI form.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is this your app main form or some other child form? Also, what have you researched and tried? What is issue you are facing?

Comment: I did found the code to do it long ago (Now this code is lost). which allowed me to show each form only once.And 2nd request to show the form will open the same window.

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before opening the form from your code, check the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property and see if the form exists in the collection.

Something like:

```
if ((Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1) != null)
{
 //Form is already open
}
else
{
// Form is not open
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use show\hide methods for opening your form. You also need to initialize all form fields after each time you show this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable with default value false which you set to true once the form was shown, and check the variable on form opening.