# Check If windows Form open C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have main form `frm_main` have menu strip and I have other Form `frm_clients`
now when I open `frm_clients` using menu strip in `frm_main`
I need to check if `frm_clients` opened 
if it open don't open other just show it 
if not open open it

here the code

```
        private void clientsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PL.frm_clients frm = new frm_clients();
            frm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, using ShowDialog() could be an option instead of show as this would keep the control at the front of the application until the window is closed.

Comment: but the method ShowDialog can't return to the frm_main until close frm_clients

Comment: Would this not be a sub menu that is being looked at? Would you not want it to be closed before continuing? Else what is their connection

Comment: here the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351925/open-windows-form-only-once-in-c-sharp