# Only allow to open the window once

Tags: c#, winforms, button, properties, window

I have created a simple Windows Form which opens up as a Properties window after a button click,
now as you know, a Properties window should only be opened once, and since I'm a beginner, I'm dependent on your advice:
How do I make this window only appear once?
here is the little Code Snippet (this is not my main class - if it needs to be applied on the button method, i could also do it there)

```
public partial class EinstellungenFenster : Form
{
    public EinstellungenFenster()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = "Outlook Add-in Einstellungen";

    }
}
```

and here the Button Method i use:

```
        private void FensterOeffnen(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
    {
        EinstellungenFenster fenster = new EinstellungenFenster();
        fenster.Show();

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

instead of `fenster.Show()` use `fenster.ShowDialog()`, this will make the form modal, meaning that no other parent dialogs can be used until it is closed

Comment: This deserves more upvotes! Easiest solution to opening single instances of forms.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to block the user from doing anything else whilst the window is up i.e. forcing them to close it before they move on, call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. Otherwise, my advice would be to maintain a private field and detect whether the form has already been created/shown on click and just flash the form to bring it to the users attention.

Comment: That was better than what i asked for, thanks I'll take your answer in 6 minutes.
and Sayse is right, ShowModal() doesn't work, it has to be
ShowDialog().

Comment: Oops... I primarily use Delphi in my workplace, old habits! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if we are calling a form from a menu click on MDI form, then we need to create the instance declaration of that form at top level like this:

```
    Form1 fm = null;
```

Then we need to define the menu click event to call the Form1 as follows:

```
private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fm == null|| fm.Text=="")
    {
        fm = new Form1();              
        fm.MdiParent = this;
        fm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        fm.Show();
    }
    else if (CheckOpened(fm.Text))
    {
        fm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        fm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        fm.Show();
        fm.Focus();               
    }                   
}
```

The CheckOpened defined to check the Form1 is already opened or not:

```
private bool CheckOpened(string name)
    {
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

        foreach (Form frm in fc)
        {
            if (frm.Text == name)
            {
                return true; 
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this will solve the issues on creating multiple instance of a form also getting focus to the Form1 on menu click if it is already opened or minimized.