# Load same instance in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am facing a problem in my application. There are multiple forms which can be accessed by ***quick setup*** button in the home page,which contains ***next*** and ***back*** buttons.

And in the last form there is a ***finish*** button, which when clicked goes to another form named Scoreboard. The scoreboard form is having a user control which have ***home*** button, setting etc.

When I click on ***home*** button it goes back to home page and then when the user clicks the ***quick setup*** again, I needs to retain the previous values in the form instead of creating new instance.

In the finish button i am using this code :

```
Scoreboard sc = new Scoreboard();

sc.show();

this.hide();
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Save the values into the users session. Whoops - Winforms.. Well save the values somewhere :D

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code for the same ?

Comment: Are you working with a database? If so, use cookies and save the form data into a `Forms` table.

Comment: what are you wanting/needing to persist across instances, also does it need to be persisted over different run sessions of the application. Also how many fields are we talking about.

Comment: No , not with the database, I just want the values to remain whenever the user clicks on the Home button and then goes back to the quick setup , the old previous values should be loaded...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: Use UserSettings, remember the values ​​of variables from "quick setup" form. When you clicks the quick setup again, maybe in method FormLoad read stored values from UserSettings (Properties.Settings.Default...)  ​​to the textboxes or wherever you want.

Some help from ms
[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can go. The first is since you are loading your Scoreboard form from the same button you can just subscribe to the Scoreboard Forms [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Event and use public properties to get the information back into your parent form, you could then pass that information back to the ScoreBoard when you create the Form.  Your other option would be to use [`UserSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to persist your values in between sessions.