# C an I stop my console app opening new window everytime I click the exe using a singleton pattern and without using a mutex

Tags: c#, console-application

Can someone tell me How to ensure that the console app doesn't open a new window if one is already open when I run the exe file multiple times ?

Comment: I think you want a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C%5F.23) implemented in your app, or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: I tried using Mutex but can we also do the same using Singleton pattern ? Mutex uses Threading , instead I would like to achieve the same using OOPs ,can someone suggest thoughts in that way

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a named mutex and if there is already a mutex with that name, exit.

Comment: I tried this it worked but want to implement using singleton pattern

Comment: I tried implementing singleton on the program class but couldn't understand where should I implement the singleton to stop opening multiple instances, because whenever I click on .exe, it creates  a separate App domain and a separate instance and so a specific console window, so here the instance would be specific to app domain so can I really implement singleton in this case ? if so How can I do that Any ideas pls?

Comment: @Shekar To my knowledge you can't because each process has its own memory space, your singleton needs to do some kind of IPC in order to know there is another process somewhere, this is where the mutex comes into play