# C# unload and load form / hide and close

Tags: c#, winforms, hide, show

I am coding a simple sidescroller in C# using Windows Form Applications. I want it so when the player touches an exit point, this immediately loads a new level.

To implement this, I use the following code:

```
if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(exit.Bounds))
{
    Form2 myNewForm = new Form2();
    myNewForm.Visible = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

This works. However, it loads numerous instances of form2 - I only want it to load once. I don't know how to write this (sorry, I'm a newbie - it took me a while just to write this code!).

Also, loading a level via a new form is inefficient. Is there a way to unload the open form to load the next one in the same window/instance, rather than creating another separate window?

Sorry if this is unclear. I've done my best research + I'm new. Please don't mention XNA! Thanks.

Comment: Look at the singleton pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp

Comment: Reading through the comments, I see that this is resolved.  You should select the answer that best met your needs.  That being said, experimenting with my own winforms game, I wasn't a fan of the constant opening and closing of windows between 'levels'.  The route I took was having a main window which housed a menu bar and all the UserControls which represented all the levels or maps or whatever.  The the main window just dictates which UserControl was visible, similar to zmechanic's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a small modification to your project's Program.cs file to change the way your app decides to terminate.  You simple exit when there no more windows left.  Make it look like this:

```
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var start = new Form1();
        start.FormClosed += WindowClosed;
        start.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }

    static void WindowClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) Application.Exit();
        else Application.OpenForms[0].FormClosed += WindowClosed;
    }
}
```

Now it is simple:

```
if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(exit.Bounds))
{
    new Form2().Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I will leave this question up for future reference, should anyone have the same problem. Thanks for the help everyone. This is a great community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.OpenForms[]` collection to retrieve the Opened form instance and then Show it.

Try This:

```
Form2 frmMyForm = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["formName"];
frmMyForm.Show();
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply! I tried this but get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of the object" - sorry, I'm toying around with it but I am a newbie! I tried: Form2 frmMyForm = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
frmMyForm.Show();

Comment: try this you should give formname as `Form2` instead of `Form1` (if you didnt change it) try this: `Form2 frmMyForm = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried this but specifically for this code (frmMyForm.Show();) I get the same error. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is not in your form being loaded multiple times, but in your game logic not being suspended when the end of the level is reached. It means that your game keeps playing an old level when a new level is already loaded.

If Form1 is the main form then your whole application will shutdown. You need bootstraper which will be the entry point of your application, not the Form1. If you do that your Form1 will be a child in the same sense as will be Form2. You can open and close them without shutting down the application. If you don't know how to do that, just create another empty form, let's call it Main and make it the starting form of your application. Then hide it and open Form1 from Main form as Modal. Then when you complete level in Form1, close Form1, the code flow will return to Main form and you'll spawn Form2 from Main form as Modal. You'll have fully predictable logic, where all forms are opened from a single controlled place.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the reply. I tried changing my code to this.Close instead of this.Hide to close form1, but it ends up closing form2 too. Hmm...