# How to stop a form opening multiple times when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I would like help to make sure only one version of windows form is open each time the button is pressed on my main form, not an instance per button click
My current code is:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login PassForm = new Login();
    if (!PassForm.Visible)
    {
        PassForm.Show();
    }
   /*
    else
    {
        PassForm.BringToFront();
    }
    */
}
```

I commented the part out because it isn't working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid multiple instances of windows form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the same instance, don't go creating a new one every time.

```
private Login _passForm = new Login();

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_passForm.Visible)
    {
        _passForm.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        _passForm.BringToFront();
    }
}
```